# Discord notification causes Firefox audio to cut

Tags: sound, 20.04, notification

When listening to some music in Firefox, using the Spotify web player, or on YouTube, the playback cuts whenever I get a Discord message notification.

[image: example of this happening]

It drops about 1-1.5sec of audio playback. Interestingly, when I use `notify-send`, playback is uninterrupted.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04, all updates installed. Using a snap-installed Discord version "Stable 62918 (60261fb)".

How can I "fix" this?

Comment: Are you aware that, in my opinion, Discord is spyware, and also spams syslog (if you haven't given it permission to do stuff outside of its sandboxed environment)? It's got code that monitors what other software you're running at the same time. Also, if you check the size /var/log/syslog there's a good chance that it's huge. `tail /var/log/syslog` might show the spamming that I refer to. Anyway, I suspect that your problem is related to Discord.

Comment: @heynnema thank you for the opinion, but that's beside the question.

Comment: Maybe true, but I'd recommend checking your /var/log/syslog and /var/log/auth.log.

Comment: I mean, you are correct - there are indeed log lines in syslog related to Discord. It's just that I don't see how those are related to the problem at hand:

```apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=92286 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"```

Comment: If you look at the SIZE of `/var/log/syslog*` and `/var/log/auth.log` I think you'll find they are GIGAbytes large. If you VIEW more of syslog, you'll see that it's entirely bombed with messages like you saw. Discord is nasty, and MAY be the entire source of your problem. Does this problem occur at any other time?

Comment: Well, `syslog` is about 11M, while `auth.log` is 48K. That doesn't seem too extreme to me.